# How to make each in for loop execute in interval?

Tags: java, android

I have a global variable and a ArrayList

```
boolean resultOk;
....
ArrayList<byte[]> payloadList;
...
```

a for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<payloadList.size(); i++){
     ...
}
```

I would like each one in for loop, it will do in 5s (timeout). If in 5s, "resultOk" is true, it will move to next in for loop immediately. If the time is up, it will break for loop. How to do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job question was a little vague also this will only break the condition at the beginning of each iteration if timepassed > 5s.

```
long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i=0; i<payloadList.size() && (System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp) < 5000; i++){
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it atleast once. Use a do while loop

```
long  startTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
int i=0;
do{
...Calculations
if(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime < 5000){
break;
}
startTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
i++;
}while(i<payloadList.size());
```

I am a it confused from your statement  if the lop breaks if it is less than or greater than 5 s, so use the < / >  sign as per your requirement